# Analytics new view in existing property not showing real-time data

Tags: google-analytics

A few days ago I created a new view under the same property i´ve been using for years on my website. The property is correctly implemented through GTM and the rest of the views have been registering data without any issue, but this new view is not tracking anything. I also cannot see anything under the real time report. No filters have been added yet to the new view.

Any clues of what can be causing this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

User ID Tracking was activated. Created a new view without that option enabled and now it´s tracking fine. Note that the activation of the User ID Tracking cannot be reversed.

Comment: User-ID tracking activation is created when you create the view via the User-ID function from the Properties settings instead of creating it directly at the view level. So it's not like you can't go back, they are just two different things. The important thing though is that you found where your problem was.